# Problems caused by changing the name of my app when deploying to heroku

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

The name of my django app was always **workout**. Then, when I started to deploy it, I thought it'd be a good idea to change the name to **workoutcalendar**. So I started a new git repo and put my project files in there (not starting a new django project). The only things I changed were the name of the folder `workout` (the first one of the django project where settings.py is located) to `workoutcalendar` as well as changing the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable.

Now, I'm running into problems. It seems that parts of my app are looking for a `workout` module, which they can't find. Example:

```
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615612+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615613+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615614+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615615+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 176, in handle_request
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615616+00:00 app[web.1]:     respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615617+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 146, in __call__
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615618+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.get_response(request)
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615619+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 81, in get_response
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615620+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self._middleware_chain(request)
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615621+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 37, in inner
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615622+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615623+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615624+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615626+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615627+00:00 app[web.1]:     callback, param_dict = resolver.resolve_error_handler(500)
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615628+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 549, in resolve_error_handler
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615629+00:00 app[web.1]:     callback = getattr(self.urlconf_module, 'handler%s' % view_type, None)
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615629+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615630+00:00 app[web.1]:     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615631+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 529, in urlconf_module
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615632+00:00 app[web.1]:     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615633+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615634+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615635+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615638+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615636+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615639+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615640+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615640+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615641+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615717+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.31.130.110 - - [15/Jan/2018:13:06:40 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "-"
2018-01-15T13:06:40.615642+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'workout'
```

I don't know how to change all the relevant parts of my project. Where are the places where `workout` will be mentioned, and I need to change it to `workoutcalendar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be your [`ROOT_URLCONF`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-ROOT_URLCONF) in `settings.py`.

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'workoutcalendar.urls'
```

If you still get problems after that, then run `git grep workout` in your project directory and review the matches to see if there are any other changes you have to make.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct because it's a good answer. However, I've had a change of heart about the naming and have decided to start a new heroku app with the original name `workout`.